# PIC assembly - passing a register as argument

Tags: assembly, pic

I was trying to do this for a PIC16F device

```
clrf BIT
bsf REGISTER,BIT
```

which gives a compiling error.

However, doing this

```
clrf BIT
movf BIT,W
bsf REGISTER,W
```

gives no compiling error.

Am I doing it right, or is there a clever way to accomplish it?

Comment: How are declarated `BIT` and `REGISTER` variables?

Comment: I read somewhere that doing "bsf REGISTER,BIT" would get the address of BIT, not its value, don't know if it is true though

Comment: Read again! After `BSF` instruction follow 8 bit memory page address argument and after that 3 bit size bit address argument of page addresed byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these bits of code does what you want. The bit number is not allowed to come from a register. It must be a hard coded number.

In the first case, the assembler correctly gives an error. Why does the second case assemble then? Simply `W` is not really a register name, it is the number zero in disguise used to control the destination of instructions with a direction bit. So the code effectively is:

```
clrf BIT
movf BIT,W
bsf REGISTER,0
```

By coincidence, you write a zero to the variable `BIT` and then clear bit number zero in `REGISTER`. Your code does what you expect, but not for the right reasons.